# Is there a way to disable the native retry logic with an azure queue trigger?

Tags: azure-functions

I see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages#handing-errors-in-functions) where queues and blob triggers will cause a native retry of 5 times.  I am sure this is can very helpful in some circumstances but it is also not helpful in others.  Is there some configuration bit that can be set to remove these retries?  In the case of a function failing due to exhausting the RU of a cosmosdb binding it is unlikely that rapidly running it 4 more times will garner a different result.

Comment: maybe have a look at the host json file, there are a lot of configuration you can make on trigger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your `host.json` file to set `maxDequeueCount` to `1`:

```
{
  "queues": {
      "maxDequeueCount": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: this works but seems to have the side affect of moving the message to the poison queue regardless of success

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned if the queue is a Storage or Service Bus.

For the Service Bus, you can do the following which worked for me:-

Instead of making change in your function app, update the queue's configuration to set the "`Max Delivery Count`" as 1. This will ensure only a single dequeue operation is possible at the source end, without bothering of who is the consumer.

This works irrespective of whether the version of Function App is v1 or v2. See the screenshot of Azure Portal

[image: Service bus queue's property]